# how to add days to textbox on activereports 6 and c#

Tags: activereports

i have activereport 6 and C# and i try to add 6 days to textbox1 value/text
this is what i try

```
string text1 = this.textbox1.Text;
```

i also try

```
string text1 = this.textbox1.Text.ToString();
```

or string text1 = this.textbox1.Value

convert string to time

```
DateTime date1 = Datime.Parse(text1);
```

i keep getting error "target of invocation"
how do i convert textbox data string to datetime? or how do i fix that target of invocation error?

Answer (score 0):

That should be the correct way to get the text value from the textbox, as it is already a string.

```
string text1 = this.Textbox1.Text;
```

From there you should be able to use the standard .NET methods to convert it to a DateTime. The way you did it looks correct to me based on [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime). However, that's assuming the format your string is in is one of the formats the DateTime.Parse() method understands by default. Example from their docs:

```
string dateInput = "Jan 1, 2009";
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);
Console.WriteLine(parsedDate);
// Displays the following output on a system whose culture is en-US:
//       1/1/2009 00:00:00
```

If your string is in a different format from one of the [handful that DateTime.Parse understands by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) you may need to use a [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), and I believe that could be the source of the error you're receiving.